# Meteor debug on server side on windows with node-inspector

Tags: windows, meteor, node-inspector

I am running meteor on Windows, possibly a minority here. I searched and found solutions for Linux and possibly Mac but no one has provide solutions for Windows. Maybe someone can help?

First I modified the `meteor.bat` file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor` to included `--debug` as mentioned in other posts:

```
@echo off&&"%METEOR_PATH%\bin\node.exe" --debug "%METEOR_PATH%\app\meteor\meteor.js" %*
```

I started my node-inspector and received an instruction to visit `0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858` to start debugging

I then started my meteor application, but when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858` I saw two squares: one for Scripts, and one for console. Nothing came up when selecting Scripts.

Does Windows have the same issue as Linux, spawning two processes but only one with the debug flag?

Comment: When I brought up meteor I can see that node-inspector attached to it correctly, "debugger listening on port 5858" and confirmed that I brought up Meteor in the debugger mode. But I still don't see anything in the Scripts icon.

Comment: I noticed that when I started meteor it started two processes as well, just like in Linux. When I killed the second process it automatically started it again. When I killed the first process the application just exited. But unlike in Linux by killing the second process doesn't make it to show the server side scripts in node-inspector.

Comment: By switching to Chrome now I see all Meteor scripts but not my own. It's an improvement from running with Firefox but not helping me with the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.5.3 added the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable that passes those parameters directly to node.

So fire-up your favorite js debugger like node-inspector
Assuming you already have it installed, call

```
node-inspector
```

Then

```
set NODE_OPTIONS = --debug
meteor
```

Do this inside your project folder, you can also use the --debug-brk to break immediately on start

In Chrome open localhost:8080 in a new tab

Have fun

Comment: This gets me to exactly where I was. As per Tom Wijsman at Windows Meteor I will need to modify this file and make others changes to make my code viewable in the node-inspector https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/app/server/server.js#L92

Comment: So you can start the debugger but are unable to see your code? In versions >=0.5.3 you don't have to change the code to be able to debug. If you can access the debugger then it means the flags are being passed correctly to the node child process, or the debugger is attaching to another node process that also has a --debug flag. Use a program like Process Explorer to spy the process parameters, you should have 3 node.exe processes, 1 for node-inpector, 1 for meteor.js, and below this 2 child processes, mongo.exe and 1 node for you project. Make sure this is the one that has the debug flag set.

Comment: Yes, there are three node.exe processes. One for node.inspector and two for meteor. I run mongodb independently from meteor. The -debug process is attached to the meteor process. My questions are the following; 1. Would my application (a 3rd party vendor) needs to support the debug flag for this to work 2. If not, how do I have the debug flag attaches to my application?

Comment: I'm not sure I've got the question, but, your app does not have to support the debug flag, nor you have to do anything for it to work. If you can see the --debug flag on the deepest meteor process in the tree and if you are able to attach the debugger then the debugger is working properly, aside the fact you cant see your code. So what we have to investigate is why you cant see your code. Can you do a --debug-brk and step into your code? Does it breaks inside meteor.js? What meteor script do you see? Does your project dir has special chars? Maybe answering these questions may help.

Comment: I tried using --debug-brk. From the node-inspector browser I can see it stopped inside meteor.js. From the browser under Scripts it has two panes. One for Scripts, I can see meteor source code: meteor.js, _linklist.js,  ...util.js. Inside Content scripts there's nothing. My directory is structured as C:\Users\jhuang\Documents\WebFM\WebFM_Evan_020413 with four directories underneath: .meteor, client, public, and server.